# Pass data from an Activity to a fragment

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am a little bit lost in this, so I already passed data from my LoginActivity to my DashboardActivity. And it works now (thank god). But now, I would love to pass that data to a fragment.

I have this on my DashboardActivity:

```
Intent get = getIntent();
String userId = get.getStringExtra(LoginActivity.EXTRA_ID);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("userId", userId);
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

I have this on my Fragment:

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
String userId = bundle.getString("userId");
int uid = Integer.parseInt(userId);
```

Is it like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send data from activity to fragment in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)

Comment: This might look silly but in here:
bundle.putString(userId)
I can't pass it like this, or can I?

Comment: You need a key, like you have in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting data in Fragment and Activity are not done in the same way.
To send extra to a fragment, You can do it this way.

In your Activity Class

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("userId", "value you want to send");

FragmentClass frag = new FragmentClass();
frag.setArguments(bundle);
```

Then in Fragement onCreateView

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("userId");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

The issue with your code is you're getting the argument with a wrong id.

Right way

```
String userId = getArguments().getString("userId");
```

Comment: I know I am asking too much. I just updated my question, should it be the way I have it there? And thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: Is it normal to my DashoardFragment to crash? xD

Comment: I believe that I am not defining my Fragment well. Like, the proper way. I don't know, because I believe that the problem I have is because of the way I am passing the data from my activity to my fragment. Because the value I get in my fragment is null, while I can print the id in my activity.

Answer (score 0):

From activity to fragment you should use bundle as below

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(LoginActivity.EXTRA_ID, "Extra value");
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Then in your Fragment, get the data for example in `onCreate()` method

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
        String extraId = bundle.getString(key, defaultValue);
}
```

Comment: I am so confused, I passed my userId data as a String through the Intent. And I got it in my DashboardActivity. And now I want to have access to the userId in my Fragment, so I should use the bundle to do it?